# YUI 3. Programmatically trigger onSubmit

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

How I can trigger `onSubmit` event using code in YUI 3?

I tried this:

```
form.simulate("submit");
```

But it doesn't  work.

***EDIT:*** Problem description:

I want to show popup (`Y.Dialog`) with HTML `<form>`. The content (`<form>`) to popup loaded through AJAX (`Y.Plugin.IO`). So the problem is that when I submit form using code (`myForm.submit()`) it doesn't trigger `onSubmit` event - so I want to simulate `onSubmit` event and then submit form (I have attached form validation to `onSubmit` event).

```
             var controlBtns = [
                 {
                     handler: function() {
                         this.close();
                     },
                     label: 'Cancel'
                 },
                 {
                     handler: function() {
                       formFromPopup.simulate('submit'); // this don't work, I need it because `submit()` don't trigger `onSubmit` event
                       formFromPopup.submit();                                                              
                     },
                     label: 'Save'
                 }
             ];
             var dialog = new Y.Dialog({
                 // other settings ...,
                 buttons : controlBtns
             }).plug(Y.Plugin.IO, {
                 uri: myUri
             }).render();
```

Comment: Hi @MyTitle, I'm a member of the YUI team. `form.simulate('submit')` will not trigger the default behavior of the page, so it won't send data to the server if that's what you're trying to do. Could you give us more information on what you want the event simulation to do?

Thanks!

Comment: formFromPopup.fire('submit'); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it shoud work

```
formFromPopup.fire('submit');
```

in your handler and you can create a callback like

```
formFromPopup.on('submit', {
    //Your code for on submit here
});
```

And onSubmit is not an event but a callback function.